# Creating a table with SELECT * and include trigger definition - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Say for example you want to create a table in this manner:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

But in addition, old_table has a set of triggers defined on it.  The above statement will create new_table as a copy of old_table, but it does not create the triggers on new_table that are defined on old_table.

Can the above statement be modified to include the trigger definitions?  Obviously they could be copied over manually, but it seems reasonable that this could be achieved within the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  I've not been able to find any documentation around this specifically.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the select are totally useless

Comment: Not according to Tech on the Net - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table2.php.  But you are right.  Just tried without parentheses and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that won't work. Even if it would, as you can't have duplicate names on objects, triggers would have to be renamed *somehow* and that's not what Oracle does.

So - no, do it yourself. Use `DBMS_METADATA` built-in package to extract definitions if you don't have it in your code repository (though, it would probably be simpler if you did).

Comment: Seems like a good point regarding the index names, Though it could potentially do something to make the names unique without much difficultly.

Comment: Well, it actually does so with constraints you don't explicitly name, e.g. `create table test (id number primary key)` - there's no constraint name so Oracle *will* make one for you, named e.g. SYS_C009209. But, for CTAS ... I can't tell why Oracle didn't offer an option to "carbon copy" everything, from columns, datatypes, indexes, constraints, triggers ...

Comment: Seems like an oversight at this stage of the game.